# rosrun rviz rviz fails with "BadRequest()" error

Tags: ros, rviz, ogre, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to run the rviz program in Ubuntu 11.10 with the Electric Full version ROS installation. I start by running

`roscore`

then running

`rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node`

in a new terminal tab. Both execute without any errors.

However, when I open a new tab and run

`rosrun rviz rviz`

I receive the following error:

```
(rviz:7219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rviz:7219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rviz:7219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rviz:7219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[ INFO] [1328153638.238979048]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1328153638.239041152]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1328153638.239071158]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
  (Details: serial 13 error_code 1 request_code 138 minor_code 66)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

I know I installed all of the files and dependencies correctly (except for the `hokuyo_node`--rosdep did not recognize the package and so I had to compile it myself. It then installed with no errors or warnings.) and the same command works on a different computer.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12847/rosrun-rviz-rviz-fails-with-%22badrequest()%22-error/) by [MattConz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1726/mattconz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also have this problem. After reading this post I just kept trying and within 3-5 times it would work.

http://answers.ros.org/question/11809/rviz-crashing-at-startup-with-baddrawable

This is on a Lenovo T60p running Oneiric with Electric.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan Hickman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1822/ryan-hickman/) with karma: 46 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1